# How to place a view under a local task tab?

Tags: views, 8

For my Drupal 8 project for user view /user/* I have created one custom tab in the local tasks "Manage school":

```
 $data['tabs'][0]['user.manage_school'] = array(
     '#theme' => 'menu_local_task',
      #link' => array(
       'title' => t('Manage school'),
       'url' => ???,
      ),
     '#weight' => 8,
     '#access' => $uid == \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
  );
```

And actually under this tab I would like to insert and display a view (view.related_school_accounts.page_1). How can I do it in the way that the view is shown under the local tasks tab, so that the user can select other tab in case. If I put:

```
'url' => Url::fromRoute('view.related_school_accounts.page_1')
```

Then drupal just redirects to the view page, however, the other behaviour is expected. Any help please?